# If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices, and $AB=I$ (of suitable order) is $BA=I$ always true?

Tags: matrices

It is said that a matrix $A$ is said to be invertible if there exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB=I=BA$, but if we only know $AB=I$, can we be sure that $BA=I$?

Comment: If $A$ is square, then yes, always (see linked duplicate). If $A$ is not square, then no, never (look at the maximum ranks).

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is invertible then $$AB=I\implies ABA=IA=A\implies A^{-1}ABA=A^{-1}A\implies BA=I.$$

Comment: True if $A^{-1}$ exists.  But what about the case $A=\pmatrix{1&0&0\cr0&1&0\cr}$, $B=\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&1\cr0&0\cr}$?

Answer (score 2):

If your matrix are square, then is true. A proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i?noredirect=1&lq=1%22here%22). The proof doesn't suppose $A^{-1}$ exists. If not, for example
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\qquad
B = \frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1\\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
AB= I_2 \qquad BA = \begin{pmatrix}1& 0 &0\\ 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0& 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
$$